# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite - [DynamiteModule] Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite not found

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, admob

Implementing the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite plugin in a Xamarin.Forms Android app with a MainPage and 5 child pages, an AdView on each...

In the Android app, I get Google ads showing on the main page, but not on the child-pages I navigate to...

Stepping through the code, all seems to work, no errors thrown.

BUT

I get the following in output, if anyone can enlighten me on this...that would be most helpful!!

[Ads] This request is sent from a test device.
[DynamiteModule] Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite not found.
[DynamiteModule] Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:214106404
[DynamiteModule] Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 214106404
[Ads] #4 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.

No library or dependency is missing else it won't build and run.

**What is this - com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite?**
Why would it not be found or fail?

Thanks

CODE:
In the Manifest

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-MY APP ID"/>
```

In the Main Activity:

```
MobileAds.Initialize(this); //and yes, before the global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```

In the AdmobViewReneder:

```
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, AdView>
{
    Context _context;

    public AdMobViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { _context = context;  }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null) SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(AdView.AdUnitId)) Control.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-MY ADUNIT ID";
    }

    private AdView CreateAdView()
    {

        RequestConfiguration.Builder builder = new RequestConfiguration.Builder();
        builder = builder.SetTestDeviceIds(new string[] { "MY DEVICE ID" });
        MobileAds.RequestConfiguration = builder.Build();

        var adView = new AdView(_context)
        {
            AdSize = AdSize.Banner,
            AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-MY ADUNIT ID",
            
        };

        adView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320, 50);

        adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

        return adView;
    }
}
```

In the Main page:

```
            <local:AdMobView x:Name="AdView" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
```

In a child page, navigated to from the main page:

```
            <local:AdMobView x:Name="AdView" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
```

Comment: The information about it is so little. Can you provide more information about it such as code. You can post your project to the github and I can test it. In addition, if this is a special problem like a bug, you can post the issue to the [Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).

Comment: This is a company product, I cannot post in Github really.

Will try add code snippets but really standard Admob implementation for Xamarin.Form Android

Comment: I can't find the problem where is from your code. You can post it to the nuget package owner. Such as this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/485).